# cms adding my own style

Tags: templates, content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I have a website available to mobile (at the moment but I will look for PC in the future) which can be found  [BY CLICKING HERE](http://m.xclo.co.uk)

Now. the idea is how I want it but its a little bit annoying when adding new promotions as I am currently editing pages by hand.

I know of CMS and have tried some of them but every time I go through to the admin panel play around with it its asking me to choose a new template (joomla 1.5, wordpress, concrete5 exe)..

how can I have it so I can use my current layout as a template and configure it from there?

I currently have cms made simple installed.

thanks a lot.

kevin

Answer (score 1):

In your CMS Made Simple admin area: Go to Layout, Templates.

Choose Add New Template. The system will show you a very basic standard HTML layout with the essential CMSMS tags, e.g. {sitename} for the name of the site.

Edit the HTML shown so it matches your layout.

Give the template a name. Press submit.

In the Layout, Templates screen click the tick under "Default" column which will make your template the default for all pages.

Go to Layout, Stylesheets and choose Add a Stylesheet.  Add a name and paste in your CSS.  Press Submit.

Back in the Layout, Templates screen click Attach Stylesheets button for your template.  Choose your new stylesheet which you just created from the dropdown and click "Add a stylesheet".

Make sure you have at least one page (in Content, Pages) and view your site.